# SUM most recent ID/Product combinations for the latest date

Tags: sql

```
 select * from

     (select Id, Prodcut, Billing_date
      , row_number() over (partition by Id, product order by Billing_date desc) as RowNumber
      ,sum(Revenue)
      from Table1
      group by 1,2,3,4,1) a

      where a.rowNumber = 1
```

There are rows where **Id+product combination repeats for latest billing date** and which causing some data to be missed out. I am trying to add sum with row_number to sum all the ID&product combinations for the latest date but not able to make it work.

Can anyone please help me out here!

[Data Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqcb5.png) 
Database: Athena, Dbeaver

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this to do what you want:

```
select *
from (select Id, Product, Billing_date,
             row_number() over (partition by Id, product order by Billing_date desc) as seqnum,
             sum(Revenue)
      from Table1
      group by Id, Product, Billing_date
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your `group by` columns do not seem correct.  I'm surprised your query runs in any datbase.

Comment: Another Issue:  Somehow it is giving rowNumber 1 to different  ID+product in different dates. Like ID 001+ Product A + Date 12-02-2020  & ID 001+ Product B + Date 25-02-2019.  I only need the latest date data.

Comment: Basically, this is not pulling the ID&product combination for the LATEST DATE. Although, it is summing up the required numbers